# PHP generated Menu problem on XHTML 1 webpage

Tags: php, xhtml, menu

I am having a problem with a menu that is generated depending on whether a PHP session variable called "login" is true or false.

What it should do is when someone first navigates to the page. They will not be logged on so they will have a non logged in user menu displayed however when they login some of the menu items will change.

My menu works ok when you goto login page and login however on my homepage where you start from my menu is getting messed up by some bits of php code which are being displayed on my menu for no reason. Its the same code but it does not work.

I have checked for accidental "{]" or () or '' but there is none. It is really driving me bonkers

Here is the code

> php  session_start(); 
>   //check if
>   session variable has been initialised
>   if not then login set to false making
>   standard menu layout. 
>   if (isset($_SESSION["login"])
>   $_SESSION["login"] = ]
>   $_SESSION["login"]; else
>   $_SESSION["login"] = false;

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="css/style.css" media="Screen and (min-device-width: 481px)" type="text/css" title="Default"/>
<link type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" media="only Screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="css/mobile.css" />
<title>Heavy Metal - User Experience Jobs</title>

<meta name="author" content="anon"/>
```

```
<div id="banner">

    <img src="images/banner.jpg"  title="Banner Image" height="180" width="750"/> 
</div>

<div id="topmenu">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li>
            <ul class = "submenu1" id = "sm_1">
                <li><a class="link1" href="index.html">Home</a>

                </li>

                <li><a href = "php/latestjobs.php" class="link2" >Latest Jobs</a>

                </li>

                <li><a href = "search.html" class="link3">Search Jobs</a>

                </li>

                <li>
                <a href = "login.html" class="link4">Login</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                <?php
                if ($_SESSION["login"] == true)
                    echo    ('<a href = "php/j_details.php" class="link4">Check Details</a>');}
                else if ($_SESSION["login"] == false)
                    echo    ('<a href = "register.html" class="link4">Register</a>');
                ?>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Thankyou for your time!

Answer (score 2):

You've called your file `index.html`. Without the `.php` file extension, the server doesn't know that it's supposed to be a PHP script you want it to process, so it just returns the page verbatim, with all the `<?php` sections left in place.

Comment: I thought I could run bits of php in a HTML file using <?php  ?>

I tried renaming it to index.php but I am still getting the display error.

Comment: Paste error here. You are not shows all code but just a piece of code. No one can know what exactly is not working properly.

Comment: @pmqtr: in that pastebin—but not in the index.html link posted—you are missing a close bracket from the `if` condition.

Comment: ...Although, I can't work out what you're trying to do with that code. The first time you access a page it'll give you a session with `login` set to `FALSE`, then the second time, it'll notice that `login` is set, and thus set it to `TRUE`, regardless of whether you have actually logged in.

Answer (score 0):

U have too much syntax errors and other...

Replace this code:

```
<?php
 session_start();
 //check if session variable has been initialised if not then login set to false making standard menu layout.
 if (isset($_SESSION["login"])
 $_SESSION["login"] = true;
 else
 $_SESSION["login"] = false;
 ?>
```

with this:

```
<?php
 session_start();
 //check if session variable has been initialised if not then login set to false making standard menu layout.
 if (isset($_SESSION["login"])) {
 $_SESSION["login"] = true;
 }
 else {
 $_SESSION["login"] = false;
 }
 ?>
```

and this:

```
                    if ($_SESSION["login"] == true)
                    echo    ('<a href = "php/j_details.php" class="link4">Check Details</a>');}
                else if ($_SESSION["login"] == false)
                    echo    ('<a href = "register.html" class="link4">Register</a>');
```

with:

```
<?php
if ($_SESSION["login"] == true) {
echo    ('<a href = "php/j_details.php" class="link4">Check Details</a>');}
else if ($_SESSION["login"] == false) {
echo    ('<a href = "register.html" class="link4">Register</a>'); }
?>
```

Understood?
I hope that will help you.

Comment: Thankyou filip but I am still getting error. What do you think is the problem? :) http://i.imgur.com/UGYE6.png

Comment: From that image I could make two conclusions. First, that file where you put your php code don't have extension "*.php" or your server where you upload files don't running php. Maybe he runs only .ASP or someone others language, or server have problems with php processing.